# How to Organize Firebase Files into a Separate Folder on their own (functions folder not being recognized/found)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Here is the organization I'm aiming for:

```
├── firebase/
│   ├── firebase.json
│   └── ...
├── frontend/
│   ├── public/
│   └── ...
└── functions/
```

And here is my current `firebase.json`:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "/functions",
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log"
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "/frontend/public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/frontend/public/index_out.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "remoteconfig": {
    "template": "remoteconfig.template.json"
  },
  "emulators": { ... },
}
```

For the most part, `firebase deploy` didn't complain, and I've been using this configuration locally with emulators without a problem, using this command:

```bash
firebase emulators:start \
    --config firebase/firebase.json \
    --only functions,firestore,auth,ui
```

However, doing something similar when deploying actually didn't work, Firebase apparently can't find the `functions` folder, despite it being at the top level:

```bash
firebase deploy \
    --config firebase/firebase.json \
    --only hosting,functions,firestore,auth
```

I did try other variations for the `"source"` field in `firebase.json` — including `../functions`, `./functions` and `functions` — but none of them worked.

`../functions` is actually what works for me locally with emulators, which makes me think the deploy behavior is a bit inconsistent overall, but this is what I get when trying to deploy:

```
...

Error: ../functions is outside of project directory
```

And this is what I get with `/functions`:

```
...

Error: could not deploy functions because the "functions" directory was not found.
Please create it or specify a different source directory in firebase.json
```

Is there a way of doing what I'm aiming for?

> I've just realized that I can share my whole repo, since it's an open source project. [Here it is](https://github.com/psygo/go-brasil-ranking/tree/9c44182e545ed7cd24b3f0ca947f521c65f846ee).